# Subclassing ImageField to compress images

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to subclass ImageField to add compression support. This is my current code.

(Right now I'm assuming that the files will be PNGs).

```
from django.utils.six import with_metaclass, string_types
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile


class CompressImageField(with_metaclass(models.SubfieldBase, models.ImageField)):
    """
    Compress image files on upload-field
    """
    def to_python(self, value):
        value = super(CompressImageField, self).to_python(value)
        if isinstance(value, ImageFile):
            im = Image.open(value.name)
            im.save(value.name, optimize=True, quality=100)
            return ImageFile(value.name)
        return value
```

However what is stored in the database is just `u''`.

Sometimes `to_python()` receives a unicode string, sometimes a ImageField. I'm guessing this is the serialization part, although `super(CompressImageField, self).to_python(value)` always returns the same type as `value`, often with an unchanged value.

Not sure what happens here. Any help is appreciated. Hopefully I've made myself clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a django package that already do that.

- [Django-imagefit](https://github.com/vinyll/django-imagefit/)
- [Django-imagekit](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit/)
- [Django-image-tools](https://github.com/bonsaistudio/django-image-tools/)